# Firebase application crashes on KitKat versions but works on higher Android versions

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to the Stack Overflow community and sorry if I have breached any rules when posting!

That being said, I am developing an application and I used Firebase to implement the chat functionality of it. The application works fine on KitKat versions except for the chat functionality. The application shows "Unfortunately crashed..." message and brings back to a previous intent, but this Firebase implementation works fine on higher Android versions such as Lollipop or Marshmallow.

I tried both dependencies `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'` and `compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.4.1+'`,but both leads to the same problem.

I believe that program logic can't have an error because the program works on higher Android versions. Any support which could be given is highly appreciated!

Comment: Post the stacktrace and logs of the crash

Comment: This is where the error starts,   I/System.out: [CDS]port[33955]
 W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fdc80)

Comment: There are methods which don't work for e.g. API level 15 but run fine on 21. They compile and you'll get a runtime error (e.g. a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) if the code runs on the wrong device. So without some code / a more detailed stacktrace it's difficult to help you.

Comment: I see, I don't think I get such a runtime error,Only error I get is the one I have posted above, until that section the program runs fine. Is there a way here to PM you @0X0nosugar?

Comment: I could open a chat room but that's not really "P", more like "around the corner".

Comment: That would be great I guess,Sorry I am new to this!